# Salesforce: Launch S-Control in a new window from VisualForce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I'm writing a VisualForce page to replace an old legacy S-Control.

Originally the Custom S-Control was launched from a Custom Button, and it opened in a new browser window (The S-Control is type HTML, and the Custom Button has Behavior:   Display in new window)

For certain old records, I want to do a similar thing from VisualForce.

So: Do HTML S-Controls have a URL that I can launch using a link? In which case, how do I figure out the URL?

Or:

Is there a way of embedding 'Custom Buttons' (that is, the buttons defined in "Setup->Customise->Account->Buttons and Links") into VisualForce pages? If so, I can embed the existing button that knows how to open the S-Control

Or:

Can you suggest some other way of doing this? Key features: Open an S-Control in a new window from VisualForce.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer from [this forum post](http://community.salesforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Launch-S-Control-in-a-new-window-from-VisualForce/td-p/181742) courtesy of aballard:

Basically, the `!Urlfor()` function can be used to get the URL of an S-Control. So, you can use an outputLink like this:

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!UrlFor($SControl.my_scontrol_name)}" 
    target="_blank">Show SControl</apex:outputLink>
```

If you need to pass an object ID to the S-Control, you can add a second parameter that calls a propery on the custom controller, e.g:

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!UrlFor($SControl.my_scontrol_name, AccountID)}"
    target="_blank">Show SControl</apex:outputLink>
```

... where AccountID is defined on the custom controller as `public string getAccountID()`

See also this [blog post at SalesforceSource](http://salesforcesource.blogspot.com/2008/12/urlfor-function-finally-explained.html) for more info on the UrlFor function.